# How to create multiple objectives iteratively in Pyomo AbstractModel?

Tags: python, scripting, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am trying to implement an `AbstractModel` that looks to optimise iteratively multiple objective functions over the same feasible set. 
Since I want to have the most transparency in the surrounding scripts, more precisely the one activating the different objective functions iteratively, I would like to contain all the objective functions in a single `obj` attribute of the model. How should I go about doing that?

Since there are two types of objectives indexed over different sets, I attempted to create both types individually and then merge the two in an `ObjectiveList`.

This would result in the following :

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model=pyo.AbstractModel()

model.i=pyo.Set(initialize=[1,2])
model.a=pyo.Set(initialize=[(1,2),(2,1)])

model.x=pyo.Var()

model.obj=pyo.ObjectiveList()

def obj_type1(model,i):
  return x**2

obj_type1=pyo.Objective(model.i,rule=obj_type1)
for key, new_obj in obj_type1.items():
  model.obj.add(new_obj)

def obj_type2(model,a):
  return x+1

obj_type2=pyo.Objective(model.a,rule=obj_type2)
for key, new_obj in obj_type2.items():
  model.obj.add(new_obj)
```

This is not working, since in the `AbstractModel`, I cannot iterate over the individual objective containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a rule:

```
def _obj(m, j):
    if j < 3:
        return m.x**2
    else:
        return m.x+1
m.obj = Objective([1,2,3,4], rule=_obj)
```

Just make sure to deactivate all but one objective before sending the model to a solver.

Comment: I do not see how this can solve my issue. How do I handle the case I showed in my example, where the index set of the first objectives is different (even of different dimension) from the second type?

Comment: You could manually map the indices of your first and second objectives to the index in the single Objective "list". I don't really understand your motivation for wanting both types of objectives in a single component or why you're using an AbstractModel.

Comment: Because it is integrated into a script that checks iteratively whether all objectives do not exceed a certain threshold (in my case 0). The surrounding script should however be oblivious of the modelling details and only feed the data and check the thresholds.

Comment: Another option would be to declare separate Objective components and loop over all the objectives in the model using `model.component_data_objects(Objective)`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! I ended up applying the mapping trick you suggested in a previous comment!